# How to create Stacked Bar Histogram in matplotlib as in ggplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, ggplot2, histogram

I am trying to visualise Age and income from UCI Adult Income dataset using stacked bar in matplotlib. Unfortunately, the results were not as I was expecting.

In R, the code is like this

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(adult, aes(age)) + geom_histogram(aes(fill = income), color = "black",binwidth = 1)
```

and the result was something like this

[image: stacked]

I was using this code:

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))
plt.hist(adult.age, bins=10, normed=None, histtype='bar', stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

Could you guys point where I was wrong?

Thanks

Comment: There's `plotnine` package that allows you do `ggplot` in python.

Comment: Your ggplot figure seems to have ~100 bins, not 10, so try changing that in your `plt.hist` call.

Comment: something like: `plt.hist([adult['age'],adult['income']], bins=10, normed=None, stacked=True)`?

Comment: Not working @politicalscientist

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to groupby on `pd.cut`, then a value count:

```
# toy data
df = pd.DataFrame({'age':np.random.normal(50,15,1000),
                   'income':np.random.normal(5e4, 1e4, 1000)})

(df['income'].gt(5e4)
 .groupby(pd.cut(df.age, bins=range(20,80)))
 .value_counts()
 .unstack(-1)
 .plot.bar(stacked=True)
)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the code is not working for the adult income dataset, thanks